# jquery buttons interaction slows down after multiple interactions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using jQuery/ javascript to draw a series of rectangles each time a particular combination of 4 buttons is selected and a 5th is clicked. The interaction slows down considerably by the time I create a 10th line of rectangles. I had previously created the same interaction but it made list elements on the webpage. Retrying the code in canvas didn't fix this.

Comment: This code is hardly to debug to us - please make a Fiddle or paste whole code (with html etc.)

Comment: I went ahead and made a jsfiddle. watch the code slow down after 10-12 lines of rectangle.

Comment: There's also a lot you could do to reduce the size of that func. Wrap the button-color reset in a function. Use a yellow_button class so you only have to set background-color to #333 once (jquery loops all the elements of the class automatically). Track the button states in an array and then do a .join('_') on it to get a single string. Then you could have an object literal or switch statement using appropriate joined arrays (example: '1_1_1_0_1'). Also the bit before the first if in MakePattern should be in its own function. Calling makePattern for 1-4 buttons obscures its purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You're compounding click events on top of each other. Every time you fire button1(), it adds another click handler. So for all of your button functions:

this:

```
$("#button1").toggle(
    function() {
    $("#button1").css("background-color","yellow");
    is1click = 1;
    makePattern();
},
function() {
    $("#button1").css("background-color","#333");
    is1click = 0;
});
```

Instead of this:

```
function button1(){
$("#button1").toggle(
    function() {
    $("#button1").css("background-color","yellow");
    is1click = 1;
    makePattern();
},
function() {
    $("#button1").css("background-color","#333");
    is1click = 0;
});
}
```

And then stop calling the functions at the end of "makePattern."

I'm not 100% sure your code will still work as expected but in its current state you will keep firing all those toggle functions more and more times every time you fire those button1-5. Toggle, the way you've used it is just a click event handler that tracks the last of those two functions fired so it can fire the other one. If you want one or the other of the toggle functions to fire when `is<1-5>Click` is set to zero, just do a standard click and write your own logic to fire functions based on the value of those vars.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I had the code before this written like you mentioned. But the toggle then failed to work after the makePattern() events were complete. The 0 values won't go back to each button unless I called each button function :/

Comment: That's because the toggles are overriding each other not because the toggle methods care what the value of is1-5Click was. That's global and is quickly changed by the multiple firings. Do a simple .click( function(){ if(is1Click===0){ doThis(); } else { doThat(); } );

.toggle was the wrong choice here I think.

Comment: you were right! this works so far. Now I feel silly for not tying the click itself in an if statement so there is still a toggle but without having to put the toggle function. fingers crossed this continues to work! THANK YOU!